# Jenkins multibranch pipeline job runs ambiguously when committed from two branches simultaneously

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I created a multi-branch pipeline and it builds one job. I used regex for handle branches so only master or development runs. And  I triggered from gitlab to pipeline. If i commit separately from master or development, it triggered pipeline and pipeline runs job in correct branch. Everything is okey.
 If i commit at same time from master and development; pipeline runs for both branch(pipeline>master and pipeline>development runs) but they use same job. So that job runs at one of them branch. I expected to run two job for each master and development branch. [image]

I cloned that job to solve my problem but i wonder that what i am missing? Can i use one job for multibranch or i should create different jobs for each branch, and is it safe for concurrent commits?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve. I assume you're triggering a non-multibranch job from within the multibranch job? You want that job to be executed once per branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `Jenkinsfile` used for the multibranch pipelin triggers another job unconditionally of the branch Jenkins does it all as expected.

To achieve that you'd need to add some additional logic. You could e.g. add the branch name as parameter to the downstream build job when triggering the build. That should trigger separate downstream builds:

```
build job: '<job name>', parameters: [string(name: 'Branch', value: env.BRANCH_NAME)]
```

You may as well just use `BRANCH_NAME`. However I usually like to use `env.BRANCH_NAME` just to signal that this is an environment variable.

**However maybe it'd better to consider the following:**

Instead of triggering another job using the `build` step you should rather integrate that job's stuff into the `Jenkinsfile` of the multibranch pipeline itself. Then it'll be executed once per branch. This is the way how you can use multibranch pipelines as efficient as possible.

Comment: I used : " stage('Deploy'){
            when {
                branch 'master'
            }steps{...}" instead of BRANCH_NAME .As i mentioned in picture, when i triggered pipelines simultaneously from two separate branch, i see only git : ref/remotes/origin/development. (ref/remotes/origin/master is absent). So it is breaks my jenkins configuration. Should i see both branch name in the pipeline or it is normal to exist only one branch name? Maybe, i shouldn't let to triggerd the pipeline from different branches in same time?

Comment: What I tried to explain was that as soon as you trigger another pipeline from your multibranch pipeline it will by default not know anything about your branches. However maybe I'm still missing the whole picture here. So you're triggering another jobs from your multibranch job. Maybe a small code snippet would help on how you do that.

Comment: Maybe i am telling in wrong way. :) For example; you have one job and one multi-branch pipeline. The pipeline builds the job. Also you are using git for trigger the your pipeline. You are working in branch A and when you commit it, your pipeline triggers. An other developer working in branch B and also he commit it in the same time. So the pipeline triggered two times and they try to run the same job in parallel. (What do you expect to see for job branch name? and How many times the job should run in that case?)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Jenkins documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/)

"The Multibranch Pipeline project type enables you to implement different Jenkinsfiles for different branches of the same project. In a Multibranch Pipeline project, Jenkins automatically discovers, manages and executes Pipelines for branches which contain a Jenkinsfile in source control."

If you have checked in the Jenkinsfile in source control then Jenkins should create build jobs for each branch you have.

As you mentioned " I used regex for handle branches so only master or development runs" there should be something wrong in configuration. This is not required for multibranch project.

Comment: Yes not needed but i filtered, because i like to see the branches to be discovered on Jenkins panel, when i click pipeline :). 

Jenkins, creates/builds jobs for each branch i have when i assign different jobs or  build pipelines at different times from different branches. Only i have problem when i triggered pipeline simultaneously from each branch. (in this case : My jenkinsfiles are same  in master and development branches and i have only one job. And they build the same job.).